# Hive query failed: Cannot recognize input near 'LEFT' '(' 'col' in select clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, hive

I am running this query in Hive

```
with missed_codes as (
SELECT col1, left(col1, 3) || '.' || substr(col1, 4) as col2 FROM "table"
)
select * from missed_codes
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:7 cannot recognize input near 'LEFT' '(' 'col1' in select clause
```

Input columns:

```
col1 
A018
B672
```

Expected output:

```
col1   col2
A018   A01.8
B672   B67.2
```

I do not get what is the issue with this query. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive does not have left() or right() functions. You can easily replace them with substr().

this is equivalent of `left(col1, 3)`:

```
substr(col1, 1, 3) --arguments are: input string, start position, number of characters
```

And the whole sentence:

```
with missed_codes as (
SELECT col1, substr(col1, 1, 3) || '.' || substr(col1, 4) as col2 FROM "table"
)
select * from missed_codes
```

Also older versions of Hive do not have `||` operator, use `concat(str1, str2, str3, ... strN)`

Comment: This adds '.' at the end of the value for eg. like A00.  How to remove that. I used regexp_replace(substr(icd10, 1, 3) || '.' || substr(icd10, 4), '\.$', '') as col2 ... But it is not working

Comment: @rshar use double back-slash for escaping dot: `'\\.$'` or use some case statements to check the length and not concatenate conditionally